# how can I display the contents of a html locally without using a browser?

Tags: html

I see some apps(such as Read it Later or instapaper) display the cleanup html locally in their own system.

I wonder how to make it?

In my short sight, I think the software itself contains a display module like browser or just display it in regular file format? I am green hand but want to know it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "browser" is mostly window dressing around a [*rendering engine*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layout_engine), the job of which is to render HTML. This rendering engine is often usable by any application separately from the browser. That's all.